# Set datasource of datagridview in module

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am writing a program that will automatically process files, based on a set of criteria. In order to process these, I need to load the Excel file first, before I can process it.

I create a module called "NewBusAuto". In here, I created a new datagridview. I am trying to set the datasource of this, but whenever I do, it doesn't actually bind. When I try and process each row/column, it is saying it is still empty.

Code used:

```
Module m_NewBusinessAutomation

Dim dgvImport As DataGridView

Public Sub NewBusAuto(ByVal folderName As String,
                      ByVal fileName As String,
                      ByVal executeScript As String)
    dgvImport = New DataGridView

    If Path.GetExtension(fileName) = ".xls" Or Path.GetExtension(fileName) = ".xlsx" Then
        Using cn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With _
                {.DataSource = folderName & "\" & fileName,
                 .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"}
            builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0; IMEX=1;HDR=Yes;")
            cn.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
            cn.Open()

            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
                Dim dr As System.Data.IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt.Load(dr)
                dgvImport.DataSource = dt
                dgvImport.Refresh()
                Messagebox.show(dgvImport.RowCount & "-" & dgvImport.ColumnCount)
                dr.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
```

The messagebox is giving me "0 - 0" as a result.
I need to load the Excel file to the actual database. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `When I try and process each row/column` there is no code there showing that and it is not clear what it means.  Nor is there anything there showing the database aspect

Comment: As @Plutonix said, there's no code here to do anything with a database. You are populating a datatable object with the sheet data from excel and then setting the datasource of a datagridview to the datatable. There's no part of this code that manipulates a database in any way. What are you really trying to do? Create a SQL table? Insert into a SQL table? Update a SQL table? Are you even using SQL at all? If so, tag your RDBMS for additional help.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code after you've loaded the DataTable.  Examine dt and see if it has any rows.  That will at least narrow down whether the problem is reading the data or binding the table.  For a DataGridView.DataSource, I've always used a BindingSource and point the BindingSource to the actual table instead of pointing the DGV to the table directly.

Comment: Added the question. When I put the messagebox in, it is showing me "0 -0", instead of "31-11". This is supposed to be a little converter, where I insert 1 file, and it converts it into a generic output so I can load it into our production system. I need to do this for multiple files, in multiple formats. The converter is reordering the file and exporting it to CSV (later in the code)

Comment: Apart from that, if I set the datasource of an actual datagridview placed on a different form, and I set the code in this script to that datagridview (so instead of dgvImport.DataSource = dt, do f_Main.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt), I get the correct number of rows and columns. So I know that there is data in the datatable